# Play Scala Application "not found: value action"

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm following the instructions in the article http://scala.playframework.org/documentation/scala-0.9.1/hello-world

I have installed Typesafe Stack 1.1 and Play! Framework 2.0 beta.

When I modify the file index.scala.html to

```
@(message: String)

@main("Welcome to Play 2.0 beta") {
    <form action="@action(controllers.Application.index)" method="GET">
        <input type="text" name="myName" /> 
        <input type="submit" value="Say hello!" />
    </form>
}
```

the page fails to compile with the error message `not found: value action`.
I have determined that it also fails to compile with other helpers. I've Googled for a solution and not come up with anything. I'm completely new to Scala and would appreciate any help.

Comment: Play 2.0 is in beta and quite different from 1.x, don't try to use the tutorials for Play 1.x with Play 2.0, it won't work. Stick with Play 1.x to learn :)

Answer (score 4):

I have just started myself with play and scala I found that play 2.0 isn't something one 
should start with.

There seems to be much lacking in play 2.0 and much of the tutorials is for play 1.x. For example I lost some time with play eclipify just to find in a bug archive that such "*comfort*" isn't implemented in play 2.0. So I would recommend to learn scala with play 1.

And in your step in the tutorial (tutorial for play 1 I dont know for play 2) you should change:

```
controllers.Application.index  to  controllers.Application.sayHello
```

add to contollers.scala

```
def sayHello = html.sayHello(params.get("myName"))
```

Add this file `helloworld/app/views/Application/sayHello.scala.html:`

```
@(name:String)

  @main(title = "Hello") {

  <h1>Hello @(name ?: "Guest")!</h1>

  <a href="@action(controllers.Application.index)">Back to form</a>

}
```

Comment: er... are you aware that Play 2.0 is still in beta, aren't you?

Comment: @Pere Villega Yes and that's why I don't recommend starting with it. I want the comfort and tutorials when learning a new framework. So I think it's better to use 1 until 2 is out of beta and have the "comfort"s implemented.